# Erro ao salvar lista de objetos relacionados

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Estou usando o `BeginCollectionItem` para fazer a inserção de objetos relacionados a um `Cliente` que chamo de `Dependentes`.

Ao salvar, tenho o erro:

> Violação da restrição PRIMARY KEY 'PK_dbo.Dependentes'. Não é possível
>   inserir a chave duplicada no objeto 'dbo.Dependentes'. O valor de
>   chave duplicada é (00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000). A instrução
>   foi finalizada.

Porque, na minha lista de objetos, não está gerando uma chave primaria. O Objeto está chegando no *controller* preenchido, apenas está faltando esse detalhe do de gerar um nova chave primária para cada `Dependente` que está relacionado ao `Cliente`.

Como posso fazer isso? Aqui está o código do *controller*:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Criar(Cliente cliente)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        cliente.ClienteId = Guid.NewGuid();
        db.Clientes.Add(cliente);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Indice");  
    }

    ViewBag.PossibleUsuarios = db.Users;
    return View(cliente);
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você já sabe a causa do erro

> Porque, na minha lista de objetos, não está gerando uma chave primaria

A solução é criar um novo Guid para cada `Dependente`, assim como é feito para `Cliente`.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Criar(Cliente cliente)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        cliente.ClienteId = Guid.NewGuid();

        foreach(var dependente in cliente.Dependentes)
        {
            dependente.DependentesId = Guid.NewGuid();
        }

        db.Clientes.Add(cliente);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Indice");  
    }

    ViewBag.PossibleUsuarios = db.Users;
    return View(cliente);
}
```